# Updating C extension for Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, cextension

I'm updating a fairly old C extension bound to a ruby gem that I didn't write.  Currently, when I execute the script that will use the C extension, I get this error:

```
symbol lookup error: /path/to/lib.so: undefined symbol: rb_str2cstr
```

There was also problems with `STR2CSTR` in the same library, which was fixed by replacing it with StringValuePtr.  My initial thought was to replace rb_str2cstr with rb_string_value_ptr, but when I try that, the C extension will not build.  I'm by no means a C programmer, and am not sure where to go with this.  I know I have to replace rb_str2cstr with its replacement, but I can't seem to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source of [`ruby.h` for Ruby 1.8.7-p357](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_357/ruby.h#L302-303) it has:

```c
/* obsolete API - use StringValue() */
char *rb_str2cstr _((VALUE,long*));
```

`StringValue` returns a `VALUE` that you can use `RSTRING` on to get the length and `char *` pointer:

```c
RSTRING(s)->len /* length */
RSTRING(s)->ptr  /* char pointer */
```

So if the existing code looked something like this:

```c
VALUE str = ...; /* The ruby String */

long  len;
char* words;
words = rb_str2cstr(str, &len);
```

Then change it to:

```c
VALUE str = ...;
str = StringValue(str);

char* words = RSTRING(str)->ptr;
long  len   = RSTRING(str)->len;
```

If you're sure that `str` is already a Ruby String then you could omit the `StringValue` call, but it'd be safer to keep it.

Comment: I guess I'm not completing following this.  I have tried to get the hang of it, but I'm not having any luck.  Here is a block of text that I have to edit: https://gist.github.com/1676278

Can you help me get this sorted out?

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/1676982. Note that becauase the type of `body` is checked against `T_STRING` you don't actually need `StringValue` in this case. `StringValue` converts "string like things" into actual strings - it's part of Ruby's duck typing. Actually getting the `char` pointer and the length is done by `RSTRING`.

Comment: @Eugene sorry, didn't @-reply you in last comment, this comment is just to sed the notification in case you didn't see it.